# Have many companies upgraded to Exchange 2010?

Tags: exchange-2010

We're looking at possibly upgrading to Exchange 2010.  Just wondering that if many other companies have done so, and if so, what the compelling features were for them in order to upgrade

Comment: We're just getting ready to upgrade to Exchange 2007 :)

Comment: One of our customers is going to exchange 2010. SO far its going well. I don't know much else on the deployment since they are handling it.

Comment: My rule of thumb is to wait for Service Pack 1 for any Microsoft product before deploying in production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the way or already did, depending on where you look.

Some compelling features are easier to deploy high availability storage and built-in archiving reducing the number of needed systems. Also the full web interface experience finally supporting other browsers than IE is a much needed change.

Answer (score 0):

I know of 3 upgrades underway, and 1 that's already completed without issue.

Answer (score 0):

We're planning an upgrade sometime in 2010 of our 2007 server, and I'm deploying my first 2010 Exchange in the next fortnight (new organisation).

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded ours to 2010 about 3 months ago.  However we are still on exchange 2007 for a transport role I haven't migrated off yet.  However our primary need was because we use macs and OWA(Outlook Web Access) in 2010 works awesome in pretty much any browser.

Answer (score 0):

Add UM; Then all your phone lines are dual use with fax! You can get rid of your fax server/machines as well as your PBX!